# NullPointerException when checking for equality between parceled custom objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm currently programming an Android app in Java which is meant to record and store workout logs from athletes in its internal storage. It should then be able to recall, edit, and delete existing workout logs. I'm getting an error when I try to check for equality between a member of my internally stored ArrayList of past workout logs and a parceled copy of one of those logs.

If I attempt to check for equality between two of the stored logs or a stored log and itself, I get the correct result with no null pointer exception. However, the error occurs when I pass my DataHandler class a log (which was parceled in my DetailActivity class) to be deleted. I get null pointer exceptions no matter where or how I try to compare this passed, formerly parceled log with my equals() method. I'm so confused by this, because I know for a fact that when I print the fields of my passed log and my stored log that I'm trying to delete, they are exactly identical. I know that equals() can't work on null objects, but this object is clearly not null because I can print its fields. Any help is appreciated.

I get the following error when trying to using copy.equals(storedObject):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.cs121.team2.workoutlog.WOLog.equals(WOLog.java:168)
            at com.cs121.team2.workoutlog.DataHandler.editLog(DataHandler.java:134)
            at com.cs121.team2.workoutlog.DetailActivity.onDeleteClick(DetailActivity.java:95)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my DataHandler class. I get the error on line:

Log.d("arraylist(1)==arrayList(1)","result: " + dummy.equals(logList.get(1)));

within my editLog method.

```
public class DataHandler extends Activity {
    private final String TAG = "Data Handler";
    public static DataHandler _dh; //the DataHandler instance that will be constructed and kept
    private static Gson gson;
    private static Type listType;
    private static Context mContext;

    private DataHandler() throws IOException { //this is a singleton class, so this is kept private
        gson = new Gson();
        listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WOLog>>(){}.getType();
        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "jsonLogs.json");
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    public synchronized static DataHandler getDataHandler(Context context) { //used to make/get the DH
        mContext = context;
        if (_dh == null) { //does the DH already exist?
            try {
                _dh = new DataHandler(); //if not, create a new one
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return _dh; //if so, just return the DH that is already instantiated
    }

    //sends the ArrayList of Logs to LLAdapter
    public synchronized ArrayList<WOLog> getLogs() throws IOException {
        //find and read data from data storage to string temp
        FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput("jsonLogs.json");
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fis.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }
        fis.close();

        //convert to non-JSON
        ArrayList<WOLog> toReturn = (ArrayList<WOLog>) gson.fromJson(temp, listType);
        if (toReturn == null){
            toReturn = new ArrayList<WOLog>();
            //TODO show user friendly error message
        }
        //send to LLAdapter
        return toReturn;
    }

    //appends a new log to the Log AList
    public synchronized void addLog(WOLog toAdd) throws IOException {
        //retrive data from file
        FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput("jsonLogs.json");
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fis.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }
        fis.close();
        //convert to non-JSON
        ArrayList<WOLog> logList = (ArrayList<WOLog>) gson.fromJson(temp, listType);

        if (logList == null) {
            logList = new ArrayList<WOLog>();
        }
        logList.add(toAdd);



        // Sorts the list of logs from oldest to newest
        Collections.sort(logList, new Comparator<WOLog>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(WOLog woLog, WOLog woLog2) {
                return woLog2.getDateCompare() - woLog.getDateCompare();
            }
        });

        // For clearing the file while testing: logList = null;

        //convert to JSON
        String jsonLog = gson.toJson(logList);
        //save to a .txt file
        FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("jsonLogs.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //write to internal storage
        fos.write(jsonLog.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }

    //edits or removes an existing log
    public synchronized void editLog(WOLog newLog, WOLog oldLog, boolean delete) throws IOException {
        //save a dummy copy of oldLog
        WOLog dummy = oldLog;
        //retrieve data from file
        FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput("jsonLogs.json");
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fis.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }
        fis.close();
        //convert to non-JSON
        ArrayList<WOLog> logList = (ArrayList<WOLog>) gson.fromJson(temp, listType);
        //for(WOLog bleh : logList) {
          //  Log.d("logList bleh",bleh.toStringList());
        //}

        if(delete) { //are we deleting the log?
            //Log.d("oldLog fields","oldLog. date: " + oldLog.getDate() + ", name: " + oldLog.getName() + ", time: ." + oldLog.getTime() + ", distance: " + oldLog.getDistance() + ", mood: " + oldLog.getMood() + ", weight " + oldLog.getWeight() + ", sets: " + oldLog.getSets() + ", reps: " + oldLog.getReps() + ", memo: " + oldLog.getMemo() + ", type: " + oldLog.getType() + ", subtype: " + oldLog.getSubtype() + ", dateCompare: " + oldLog.getDateCompare());
            //Log.d("arrayList(0) fields","arrayList(0). date: " + logList.get(0).getDate() + ", name: " + logList.get(0).getName() + ", time: ." + logList.get(0).getTime() + ", distance: " + logList.get(0).getDistance() + ", mood: " + logList.get(0).getMood() + ", weight " + logList.get(0).getWeight() + ", sets: " + logList.get(0).getSets() + ", reps: " + logList.get(0).getReps() + ", memo: " + logList.get(0).getMemo() + ", type: " + logList.get(0).getType() + ", subtype: " + logList.get(0).getSubtype() + ", dateCompare: " + logList.get(0).getDateCompare());
            //Log.d("arrayList(1) fields","arrayList(1). date: " + logList.get(1).getDate() + ", name: " + logList.get(1).getName() + ", time: ." + logList.get(1).getTime() + ", distance: " + logList.get(1).getDistance() + ", mood: " + logList.get(1).getMood() + ", weight " + logList.get(1).getWeight() + ", sets: " + logList.get(1).getSets() + ", reps: " + logList.get(1).getReps() + ", memo: " + logList.get(1).getMemo() + ", type: " + logList.get(1).getType() + ", subtype: " + logList.get(1).getSubtype() + ", dateCompare: " + logList.get(1).getDateCompare());
            Log.d("arraylist(1)==arrayList(1)","result: " + dummy.equals(logList.get(1)));
            //Log.d("contained?","oldLog contained: " + logList.contains(oldLog));
            //Log.d("arrayList(0)",logList.get(0).toStringDetail());
            //logList.indexOf(oldLog); //...if so, delete the log
            //Log.d("past remove","we got past remove(oldLog)");
        }
        else { //...if not, we're editing the log
            int myIndex = logList.indexOf(oldLog); //find the index of the old log
            logList.set(myIndex, newLog); //set the old log to the new log
        }

        // For clearing the file while testing: logList = new ArrayList<WOLog>();

        //sort loglist
        if(!logList.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(logList, new Comparator<WOLog>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(WOLog woLog, WOLog woLog2) {
                    return woLog2.getDateCompare() - woLog.getDateCompare();
                }
            });
        }
        Log.d("past sort","we got past Collections.sort");

        //convert to JSON
        String jsonLog = gson.toJson(logList);
        Log.d("past toJson","we got past jsonLog = gson.toJson(logList)");
        //save to a .txt file
        FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("jsonLogs.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d("past fos","we got past fos = mContext.openFileOutput(...)");
        //write to internal storage
        fos.write(jsonLog.getBytes());
        Log.d("past write","we got past fos.write(...)");
        fos.close();
        Log.d("past close","we got past fos.close()");
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my WOLog class with the equals method in it. The terminal says that the error happens on the return line.

```
public class WOLog implements Parcelable {
    // Just a lot of static data
    final static int TYPE_CARDIO = 0;
    final static int TYPE_STRENGTH = 1;
    final static int TYPE_CUSTOM = 2;
    final static int SUBTYPE_NONE = 0;
    final static int SUBTYPE_TIME_BODY = 1;
    final static int SUBTYPE_DIST_WEIGHTS = 2;

    final static String[] MOOD_ARRAY = {"awful", "bad", "k", "good", "perfect"};
    final static String[] TYPE_ARRAY = {"Cardio", "Strength", "Custom"};
    final static String[] SUBTYPE_ARRAY = {"None", "Time/Body", "Distance/Weights"};

    // Data stored in log
    private int dateCompare;
    private String date, name, time, distance, mood, weight, sets, reps, memo, type, subtype;

    //tag for debug logging.
    private static final String TAG = "WOLog";

    public WOLog()
    {
        dateCompare = 0;
        date = name = time = distance = mood = weight = sets = reps = memo = type = subtype = null;
    }


    // Setter Methods
    public void setDate(int m, int dy, int yr, int hr, int min){
        date = m + "-" + dy + "-" + yr + " " + hr + ":";
        if (min < 10) date += "0" + min;
        else date += min;

        dateCompare += min;
        dateCompare += hr * 10;
        dateCompare += dy * 1000;
        dateCompare += m * 100000;
        dateCompare += yr * 10000000;
    }

    public void setName(String t){ name = t; }

    public void setTime(String t){ time = t; }

    public void setDistance(String d){ distance = d; }

    public void setReps(String r){ reps = r; }

    public void setSets(String s){ sets = s; }

    public void setWeight(String w){ weight = w;}

    public void setMood(String m){ mood = m; }

    public void setMemo(String m) { memo = m; }

    public void setType(String t) { type = t; }

    public void setSubtype(String t) { subtype = t; }


    // Getter Methods
    // TODO: Remove these if we don't wind up using them for stats
    public int getDateCompare(){ return dateCompare; }

    public String getDate(){ return date; }

    public String getName(){ return name; }

    public String getTime(){ return time; }

    public String getDistance(){ return distance; }

    public String getReps() { return  reps; }

    public String getSets() { return sets; }

    public String getWeight() { return weight; }

    public String getMood(){ return mood; }

    public String getMemo() { return memo; }

    public String getType() { return type; }

    public String getSubtype() { return subtype; }


    // toString formatted with HTML for ListView
    public String toStringList(){
        String s = "";

        s += "<center><b>" + name + "</b>";

        if(date != null){
            s += "<br><b>Date: </b>" + date;
        }
        if(mood != null){
            s += "<br><b>Mood: </b>" + mood;
        }

        s += "</center>";

        return s;
    }

    // toString formatted with HTML for DetailView
    public String toStringDetail(){
        String s = "";

        s += "<center><b>" + name.toUpperCase() + "</b><br>";
        s += "<b>(Workout Info):</b><br>";

        if(date != null && !date.isEmpty()){
            s += "<b>Date: </b>" + date + "<br>";
        }

        if(time != null && !time.isEmpty()){
            s += "<b>Time: </b>" + time + "<br>";
        }
        if(mood != null && !mood.isEmpty()){
            s += "<b>Mood: </b>" + mood + "<br>";
        }
        if(distance != null && !distance.isEmpty()){
            s += "<b>Distance: </b>" + distance + "<br>";
        }
        if(weight != null && !weight.isEmpty()) {
            s += "<b>Weight: </b>" + weight + "<br>";
        }
        if(sets != null && !sets.isEmpty()) {
            s += "<b>Sets: </b>" + sets + "<br>";
        }
        if(reps != null && !reps.isEmpty()) {
            s += "<b>Reps: </b>" + reps + "<br>";
        }
        if(memo != null && !memo.isEmpty()) {
            s += "<b>Memo: </b>" + memo + "<br>";
        }

        s += "</center>";

        return s;
    }

    // TODO: Write comparable function in WOLog instead of overriding in DataHandler?

    //Equals function
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherLog){
        //return true if objects are identical
        if (this == otherLog) {
            return true;
        }
        //return false if the otherLog is null
        if (otherLog == null) {
            return false;
        }
        //return false if other object is wrong type
        if (!(otherLog instanceof WOLog)) {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.getDate().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getDate()) &&
                this.getName().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getName()) &&
                this.getTime().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getTime()) &&
                this.getDistance().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getDistance()) &&
                this.getMood().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getMood()) &&
                this.getWeight().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getWeight()) &&
                this.getSets().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getSets()) &&
                this.getReps().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getReps()) &&
                this.getMemo().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getMemo()) &&
                this.getType().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getType()) &&
                this.getSubtype().equals(((WOLog)otherLog).getSubtype()));
    }

    //in case this project ever uses hash coding, make sure they know they have to write it
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    //The following functions allow for a WOLog to be passed as a Parcel
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<WOLog> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<WOLog>() {
        public WOLog createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new WOLog(in);
        }

        public WOLog[] newArray(int size) {
            return new WOLog[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(dateCompare);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(time);
        dest.writeString(distance);
        dest.writeString(mood);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(memo);
        dest.writeString(weight);
        dest.writeString(sets);
        dest.writeString(reps);
        dest.writeString(type);
        dest.writeString(subtype);
    }

    private WOLog(Parcel in) {
        dateCompare = 0;
        dateCompare = in.readInt();
        name = null;
        name = in.readString();
        time = null;
        time = in.readString();
        distance = null;
        distance = in.readString();
        mood = null;
        mood = in.readString();
        date = null;
        date = in.readString();
        memo = null;
        memo = in.readString();
        weight = null;
        weight = in.readString();
        sets = null;
        sets = in.readString();
        reps = null;
        reps = in.readString();
        type = null;
        type = in.readString();
        subtype = null;
        subtype = in.readString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If any of the fields of your `WOLog` object are null, that `equals` method will NPE.  It's best to use the `equals` method generated by your IDE.  No point in reinventing wheels.

Comment: Indeed. Android Studio Code Menu > Generate > equals() and hashCode() option works to solve this problem. Thanks so much for pointing me towards auto-generation!

Comment: @SamuelJackson Instead of changing title to say "SOLVED" you should  write out an answer (in the answer section, not the question) and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ApacheCommons' EqualsBuilder class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

Comment: There's no need to use Apache's. I've used Android Studio's auto-generation (see comments above) and it worked for me. I just didn't know that it was there, as I'm new to AS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! If you already have the dependency though, its pretty cool as a one liner :)